# How to set up SASS to work with Django and AWS S3

Tags: css, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, sass

I'm trying to set up my Django project to use SASS, unsuccessfully so far.

1. I've installed `libsass`, `django-compressor`, and `django-sass-processor`.
2. My settings.py includes these lines:

   ```
   INSTALLED_APPS = [
        'sass_processor',
        .... [my other apps here]
   ]
   STATICFILES_FINDERS = [
       'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
       'sass_processor.finders.CssFinder',
   ]
   SASS_PROCESSOR_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static/css')

   AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.environ['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID']
   AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.environ['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
   AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'myproj-debug' if IS_DEBUG else 'myproj'
   AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = '%s.s3.amazonaws.com' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME

   AWS_S3_OBJECT_PARAMETERS = {
       'CacheControl': 'max-age=86400',
   }
   AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = 'public-read'
   AWS_LOCATION = 'static'
   STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
   DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'myproj.storage_backends.MediaStorage'
   STATIC_URL = "https://%s/%s/" % (AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN, AWS_LOCATION)
   ```
3. My base.html includes these lines:

   ```
   {% load sass_tags %}
   <link href="{% sass_src 'app.scss' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
   ```

When I run my debug Django server with `./manage.py run server`, the processor seems to find my `app.scss` file okay, because when I move it to a different location I get an error. But where is the compiled `app.css` file being placed?

I see in my page source that the `{% sass_src` line becomes `<link href="https://myproj-debug.s3.amazonaws.com/static/app.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">` but no file shows up there. (I'd actually like to have it placed at `https://myproj-debug.s3.amazonaws.com/static/css/app.css` but that's another matter.)

How do I get `app.css` to compile and show up in my AWS S3 bucket like it should?